# How to work with a recursive function with 2 recursive instances?

Tags: recurrence-relations, closed-form

**In class, we figured out how to find the closed form of a recursive definition through the "basic 5 steps method".**

Example function T(n):
If n = 1, T(1) = 1
If n > 1, T(n) = T(n-1)+1

Step 1: Iterate through a few times:

k = 1
T(n) = T(n-1)+1

k = 2
T(n) = T(n-2)+2

k = 3
T(n) = T(n-3)+3
...etc.

Step 2: find a pattern

T(n) = T(n-k)+k

Step 3: solve for k

n - k = 1
k = n - 1

Step 4: substitute k into original...
Step 5: prove via induction...

**However this has me a bit confused with 2 instances of recursion in the same function:**

Eg:
If n = 0, T(n) = 1
If n = 1, T(n) = 2
If n > 1, T(n) = T(n-1)+ T(n-2)

I'm not quite sure what to do for step 3 in this case as everything i've tried so far has failed for step 4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a feeling this 5 step method of yours won't work here (without modifications).

Comment: If you're OK with vectors, apply your method to te vector $T^\prime(n) = \begin{pmatrix} T(n+1) \\ T(n)\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: I don't think vectors are allowed here.